# Работоспособность анотаций

Tags: java

Читая разные колы я увидел то что аннотации могут стоять на разных местах, например:

```java
@Nullable
Strings name;
```

Или же в средине метода:

```java
void a(@Nullable Object a, Object1, a1){
}
```

Как работают анотации в разных местах?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аннотация `@Nullable` означает, что что-то может быть `null`. Ведь `able` переводится с английского как "способный".

> Как аннотации работают в разных местах?

Я буду говорить конкретно про аннотацию `@Nullable`(именно она была указанна в вопросе!), так как другие аннотации могут работать по-другому. Вот варианты, где она обычно может стоять.

1. Аннотация `@Nullable` к полю класса. У вас в вопросе был такой пример:

```
@Nullable
Strings name;
```

Тут всё просто, как никогда: в данном случае аннотация означает, что поле может быть `null`.

2. Аннотация `@Nullable` к методу. Вот пример:

```java
public class Test {

   private String string;
   
   @Nullable
   public String someMethod(){
      return string;
   }
}
```

В таком случае данная аннотация даёт понять, что метод может вернуть `null`.

3. Аннотация `@Nullable` к параметру метода(а не "в середине метода"). Тоже всё просто, аннотация даёт понять, что может по параметрам может придти `null`:

```
public void someMethod(@Nullable Object object){
  //Код метода
}
```

Вот как работает `@Nullable` в разных местах. Надеюсь, мой ответ полезен
=). В в вопросе была указана аннотация `@Nullable`, я отвечал про неё, а остальные, как я говорил, могут работать по-другому. Если в ответе что-то не так, пишите в комментариях, я его перепишу или дополню.